# Class for Selected Menu using wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I create Widget for Vertical menu
Now I am trying to get selected or current menu using

```
`wp_nav_menu`
```

Any one know how to Add current class when selected in `wp_nav_menu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is one extra tag is added in to **LI** >>>>>>>> **data-menu-active="2"** using this you can add extra class active or selected using jquery or javascript

Comment: thanks I already Apply that tactic and its work for me check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#_menu-3 ul li").each(function(){
  if(typeof jQuery(this).attr('data-menu-active') != 'undefined' ){
     jQuery(this).addClass('_current');
     jQuery(this).find('a:first').addClass('_current');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It should already have a class `current-menu-item`